# Should I use a gate resistor for FQP30N06L if my gate is connected to GPIO 3.3 volt of a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: mosfet, resistors, pwm, raspberry-pi

Do I really need a gate resistor for FQP30N06L if I have connected my gate to a GPIO 0-3.3 volt of a Raspberry Pi and the GPIO is going to PWM about 100-300 Hz.

It feels like if I put a resistor between GPIO and gate, then the resistor is going to create a damping effect. Right? The higher frequency I have, the less voltage is going to attach to the gate pin of the FQP30N06L?

The threshold voltage is between 1.0 to 2.5V for the FQP30N06L.

I'm not talking about connecting a resistor between gate and GND.

https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/General/FQP30N06L.pdf

Comment: Hi, If you do not put a resistor, you have to be sure that the current flowing into the input capacitance of your MOSFET will not burn your driver. I m not talking about overshoot and undershoot that could also burn your driver or your MOSFET as without damping resistor, you have an LC circuit. Generally driver made for driving MOSFET are self regulated to do not burn but I do not think that it is your case. Actually driving a MOSFET with a GPIO is a bad idea as it slows down your switching speed

Comment: What is the absolute maximum current of the GPIO pin? You need a resistor to limit the inrush below the maximum. If the maximum is 1mA. Then for a 3.3V you would need at minimum a 3.3kohm resistor.

Comment: @Jess So If I put a 1 kOhm between GPIO and gate then?

Comment: @Jess https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GrvvkYTW_0k&feature=youtu.be&t=170&fbclid=IwAR2Nnb1NCBkNifqSmVLXuIvPLBKHxPABVYbnvZKy8OOr_h6MD8D7Wrf51Ak

Comment: @vini_i Inrush? For the GPIO? I have connected a 1 kOhm between my Raspberry Pi 4 GPIO pin to the gate.

Comment: @vini_i The maximum current for the GPIO is 16 mA.

Comment: The gate of the MOSFET is a small capacitor. The GPIO is effectively a switch. That switch can go 0v and 3.3v. When the gate is at 0v and the GOIO connects 3.3v there will be a momentary high current limited by the resistance of the circuit. If that resistance is the ESR of the capacitor (IE no resistor) then the GPIO pin will get damaged. For 16mA you need at minimum 207 ohm resistor. A 1k ohm will work.

Comment: @vini_i Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I put a resistor between GPIO and gate, then the resistor is going to
> create a damping effect. Right?

Yes. Series resistance is good. Without damping the Gate capacitance and wiring inductance form a high Q tuned circuit that 'rings', causing possibly unacceptable EMI or even circuit misoperation.

> The higher frequency I have, the less voltage is going to attach to
> the gate pin of the FQP30N06L?

Not exactly. The resistance and capacitance form an RC low pass filter. With a step input this causes the voltage to rise and fall according to the equation \${Vc}(\text{t})= \text{V}(1-\text{e}^{\text{t}/\text{RC}})\$, like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC_circuit#Time-domain_considerations):-

[image]

The result is that the FET turns on and off slower, spending more time in the 'linear' region where it has both significant voltage across its Drain-Source channel and current through it. Power = voltage x current, so it will heat up more than with fast transition times. How much more depends on the transition time, supply voltage, Drain current, and PWM frequency.

> The threshold voltage is between 1.0 to 2.5V for the FQP30N06L.

At its threshold voltage your FET is *just starting* to turn on, limiting load current to 0.25mA. To fully turn on it needs 5V or more. At 3.3V you will be lucky to get 1 A with a voltage drop of 1 V, dissipating ~1 watt of power in the FET. If you are unlucky and your FET has higher than typical threshold voltage it will be even worse.

Worse again, the RC charging waveform slows down as it approaches 3.3 V, so the FET will turn on *much* slower than it would with higher voltage Gate drive.

As these graphs from the datasheet show, 3.3 V Gate voltage typically limits current to between 1 and 2 amps, and doesn't even reach the plateau voltage (horizontal part in figure 6) where the FET turns fully on.

[image]

[image]

To fix this you could use a simple level shifter like this (which is readily available as a module for I2C applications):-

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffVlkW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Alternatively you could just use a FET rated for 2.5 V Gate drive.

> the GPIO is going to PWM about 100-300 Hz.

This is good. The low PWM frequency means the FET only transitions through the linear (high power) region a few hundred times per second, so slow turn on/off times will probably be acceptable *if* the Gate voltage issue is addressed.

Comment: I'm using 1 kOhm between gate and GPIO :)